# MS Access repeat a click event of a command button using Auto Repeat?

Tags: vba, ms-access

Hi i have a command button which will trigger some code when clicked,

```
Private Sub Command46_Click()
Dim a As Long
Dim b As String
Dim c As Variant



a = DDEInitiate("EXCEL", "[START UP.XLSM]Sheet1")
b = "R1C1"

c = DDERequest(a, b)

Me.txt_qAUDUSD = c

Application.DDETerminate a

End Sub
```

this code will refresh the quote in a text box.

what i want to achieve is for this quote to auto-refresh after the command button has been pressed.

I know the auto repeat property will allow me to achieve this if I keep my mouse button pressed but this is unpractical because I won't be able to do anything else!

any help is welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Place this code to `Timer` form event and on button press set form property `TimerInterval` to refreshing time in miliseconds, for instance `Me.TimerInterval = 1000` will start quote refresing for every one second.